# Динамическая компиляция общего DbContext на основе нескольких имеющихся

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, модульность, модули, entity-framework-core-2

Мне необходимо создать для сайта ASP.NET Core 2.2 модульную систему.
Используется EF Core 2.2

У меня есть основной сайт SiteCore и модули к нему.

Сайт имеет свой DbContext, он заранее определён.

Модули могут иметь свои DbContext, и знают про DbContext из SiteCore.

Внутри DbContext у модуля могут быть таблицы DbSet из SiteCore, в том случае если в модуле я работаю с этими таблицами.

Нужно научиться собирать и компилировать общий для сайта и модулей DbContext на основе кода DbContext у сайта и модулей.

То есть проанализировать dll сайта, проанализировать dll-и модулей и на их основе скомпилировать DbContext.dll содержащий все таблицы с SiteCore и с модулей и вызывающий в своём OnModelCreating последовательно все OnModelCreating сайта и модулей начиная с SiteCore

**Добавлено:**
Похоже что получается решить задачу другим путём, без динамической компиляции. Вопрос оставляю, так как как такое сделать тоже интересно. В ответ хочется увидеть рабочий код.

Comment: @Alexander в моём случае я использую паттерн репозитория, который прячет в себе контекст базы. Кроме того планировалось для каждого DbContext сделать свой IDbContext а потом общий скомпилированный отнаследовать от всех этих I. И возвращать его в Repository через Di.

Comment: @Alexander тут речь не шла о том, что бы сделать красиво, а нужно было сделать что бы работало, так как на тот момент я других вариантов просто не видел, но сейчас нашёл хороший вариант, и его делаю. Посмотрим что выйдет в результате.

Comment: @Alexander продолжая что писал выше, во всех модулях я бы использовал IDbContext этого модуля, и его сигнатура известна заранее, но в реализации лежал бы скомпилированный контекст.

Comment: Ага, теперь понял.