# Как можно исключить определённые таблицы из системы миграций EF Core 2.2?

Tags: миграция, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2

У меня есть `DbContext` такого вида

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, UserGroup, int>
{
    public DbSet<Xxx1> Xxx1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Xxx2> Xxx2 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Yyy1> Yyy1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Yyy2> Yyy2 { get; set; }
}
```

Мне нужно сделать так что бы при миграциях всё что касается таблиц `Xxx` участвовало в миграциях, а `Yyy` - игнорировалось.

Так же необходимо игнорировать все таблицы связанные с `IdentityDbContext`

Как можно это сделать?

**Для чего мне это нужно.**

Я делаю систему модулей для сайта.
База сайта это SiteCore
Каждый модуль может содержать дополнительные таблицы по отношению к SiteCore
Но для удобства Linq запросов в базу модуль так же может работать с таблицами SiteCore (и других модулей, если он от них зависит).

Что бы миграции при таком подходе работали, мне нужно делать отдельную таблицу миграций на каждый модуль (название таблицы можно настроить в EF). Но проблема в том что модуль может содержать таблицы которые есть в других модулях, и это сломает миграции, так как тогда за одну таблицу будет отвечать сразу несколько миграций в разных модулях.

Поэтому мне надо исключить некоторые таблицы из миграций конкретного модуля.

Так же желательно что бы при `db.EnsureCreated` эти таблицы тоже не участвовали.

Вот связанный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922040/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-dbcontext-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F), где я пробую использовать другой подходи для всей этой ситуации, но на данный момент выбран подход из текущего вопроса.

**Добавлено:**

Пока думаю про такое решение:

Сделать два контекста, один для миграций, второй для работы.
При создании базы или работы с миграциями я буду использовать укороченный контекст, где `Yyy` закомментировано.
А для работы внутри модуля буду использовать нормальный полный контекст.

Comment: так удалите эти таблицы и все, из контекста 
`public DbSet<Yyy1> Yyy1 { get; set; }`
`public DbSet<Yyy2> Yyy2 { get; set; }`

Comment: @pasha тогда я не смогу с ними работать через DbContext и Linq

Comment: Добавляю что в этих таблицах связанные данные, то есть в таблице Xxx есть ссылки на Yyy

Comment: так а как вы с ними хотите работать, если вы не хотите создавать их?

Comment: @pasha а создавать их будет другой контекст из SiteCore (или того модуля который их определяет)

Comment: либо создавайте одну базу, либо несколько разных контекстов(в таблтцах будете хранить id внешнего ключа).

Comment: @pasha база будет одна, но для каждого модуля свои миграции и своя таблица миграций.

Comment: То есть для доступа к базе у каждого модуля будет свой контекст.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87228/discussion-between-pasha-goroshko-and--).